# SQL to find rows on condition OR condition in other table

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables with the columns within parenthesis:

```
users (id, active, permissions)
auths (id, user_id, active)
```

To find the active users I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.active = 1 OR users.permissions IS NOT NULL
```

I want to change the query so that it no longer considers permissions BUT it considers that a user is active also if its associated auths (if it exists) has active = 1

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN auths ON auths.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.active = 1 OR auths.active = 1
```

But I am not getting the expected results. Can someone tell me where is my error?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, expected results, and actual results.

Comment: Use an EXISTS() condition instead of a JOIN.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here for someone to write a good answer. Can you show some sample data and explain how the result you're getting differs from the result you expect? Also, can there be multiple records in the `auths` table for a single user?

Comment: Switch from outer to inner join.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
     *
from
     users
where
     users.active = 1 and
     exists(
          select 
               1 
          from 
               auths 
          where 
               auths.user_id = users.id and
               auths.active = 1
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE active = 1
OR id IN(SELECT user_id FROM auths WHERE active = 1 )
```

You can also use `UNION` and `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
JOIN
(
    SELECT id FROM users 
    WHERE active = 1
    UNION
    SELECT user_id AS id FROM auths
    WHERE active = 1
) a on a.id = user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you take the active users minus the users with active =0 in aauth:

```
select * 
from users left join   (select * from auths where auths.active =0) tab2 on users.id = tab2.user_id
where tab2.user_id is null
and users.active = 1;
```

this has some limitation

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE active = 1
and id not in (SELECT user_id FROM auths WHERE active = 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id             INT,
    ACTIVE         BIT,
    permission     BIT
)
CREATE TABLE auths
(
    id          INT,
    USER_ID     INT,
    ACTIVE      BIT
)

INSERT INTO users
VALUES
  (
    1,
    1,
    1
  ), (2, 0, 1), (3, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO auths
VALUES
  (
    1,
    1,
    1
  ), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 0)

SELECT *
FROM   users u
       INNER JOIN auths a ON  u.id = a.[user_id] AND a.active = 1
WHERE  u.active = 1
```

[image]